# Adding Pop-up feature in OpenLayers WebGIS

Tags: openlayers, geojson, popup

I have some problems with popups in OpenLayers, where the popup didn't show up. I'm using Geojson for 2 vector layers, and I want only to show the column "Route, Ramp, and Canopy" for the Bus Stops and "Routes" for the Bus Routes.

I already have this code, but it still didn't show up. What do I have to do with my code now?

```
// Add a click event listener to the bus routes layer
BusRoutes.on('click', (evt) => {
  // Get the clicked feature
  const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, (feature) => feature);
  if (feature) {
    // Get the properties of the feature
    const properties = feature.getProperties();
    // Create the popup content
    const content = createPopupContent(properties);
    // Create the popup overlay
    const popup = new Overlay({
      element: document.createElement('div'),
      autoPan: true,
      autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250,
      },
    });
    // Set the content of the popup
    popup.getElement().innerHTML = content;
    // Set the position of the popup
    popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
    // Add the popup overlay to the map
    map.addOverlay(popup);
  }
});

// Add a click event listener to the bus stops layer
BusStops.on('click', (evt) => {
  // Get the clicked feature
  const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, (feature) => feature);
  if (feature) {
    // Get the properties of the feature
    const properties = feature.getProperties();
    // Create the popup content
    const content = createPopupContent(properties);
    // Create the popup overlay
    const popup = new Overlay({
      element: document.createElement('div'),
      autoPan: true,
      autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250,
      },
    });
    // Set the content of the popup
    popup.getElement().innerHTML = content;
    // Set the position of the popup
    popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);    
    // Add the popup overlay to the map
    map.addOverlay(popup);
  }
});

// Close the popup when the map is clicked
map.on('click', () => {
  map.getOverlays().forEach((overlay) => {
    map.removeOverlay(overlay);
  });
});
```

**UPDATE v.1**
I have updated the code but it still doesn't work for me. This is my new code.

```
// Define a function to create the popup content
function createPopupContent(properties) {
  // Create an array to store the HTML content for the popup
  const content = [];
  // Loop through each property and add it to the content array
  for (const key in properties) {
    if (properties.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      content.push(`<b>${key}:</b> ${properties[key]}`);
    }
  }
  // Join the content array with line breaks to create the HTML content for the popup
  return content.join('<br>');
}

map.on('click', (evt) => {
  map.getOverlays().getArray().slice().forEach((overlay) => {
    map.removeOverlay(overlay);
  });

  const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
    evt.pixel,
    (feature) => feature,
    {layerFilter: (layer) => layer === BusRoutes}
  );
  if (feature){
    // Get the properties of the feature
    const properties = feature.getProperties();
    // Create the popup content
    const content = createPopupContent(properties);
    // Create the popup overlay
    const popup = new Overlay({
      element: document.createElement('div'),
      autoPan: true,
      autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250,
      },
    });
  }

  const feature2 = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
    evt.pixel,
    (feature) => feature,
    {layerFilter: (layer) => layer === BusStops}
  );
  if (feature2){
    // Get the properties of the feature
    const properties = feature2.getProperties();
    // Create the popup content
    const content = createPopupContent(properties);
    // Create the popup overlay
    const popup = new Overlay({
      element: document.createElement('div'),
      autoPan: true,
      autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250,
      },
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLayers does not support click events on layers, but you can filter `forEachFeatureAtPixel` with a layer filter.

I presume you want to clear existing popups before adding new ones, but you should avoid removing items from a live collection or array in a `for` loop or `forEach` as the remaining items are moved up the list and you will end up removing every second item.  You can use `slice` to make a static copy of the array.

```
map.on('click', (evt) => {
  map.getOverlays().getArray().slice().forEach((overlay) => {
    map.removeOverlay(overlay);
  });

  {
    const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
      evt.pixel
      (feature) => feature,
      {layerFilter: (layer) => layer === BusRoutes}
    );
    if (feature) {
      // add popup for bus route
    }
  }

  {
    const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
      evt.pixel
      (feature) => feature,
      {layerFilter: (layer) => layer === BusStops}
    );
    if (feature) {
      // add popup for bus stop
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I have updated the code, but it still doesn't work for me. My new code is in my question up there

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. I forget to add the map.addOverlay() for my popup.